# PostsController@destroy not defined in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, methods

stuck with this error any help would be much appreciated. The error I'm getting is below:

Action App\Http\Controllers\PostsController@destroy not defined. (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\lsapp\resources\views\posts\show.blade.php)

I do have the "destroy" method in the PostsController and using the latest vision of Laravel.

```
{!!Form::open(['action' => ['PostsController@destroy', $post->id], 'method' => 'POST', 'class' => 'pull-right'])!!}
    {{Form::hidden('_method', 'DELETE')}}
    {{Form::submit('Delete', ['class' => 'btn btn-danger'])}}
{!!Form::close()!!}
```

Comment: Try to write `App\Http\Controllers\PostsController@destroy` instead of `PostsController`

Comment: Thanks but tried that, no luck.

Comment: Sorted PostController@destroy it should have been.

Comment: So you just had an "s" too much "PostsController" instead of "PostController"?

Comment: Yes, Typo should have been PostController.

Answer (score 4):

Try this.
I changed ACTION to URL.

```
    {!!Form::open(['url' => ['posts', $post->id], 'method' => 'POST', 'class' => 'pull-right'])!!}
        {{Form::hidden('_method', 'DELETE')}}
        {{Form::submit('Delete', ['class' => 'btn btn-danger'])}}
    {!!Form::close()!!}
```

Answer (score 2):

Syntax gets changing in laravel versions frequently. So always check your version.
Right now i think you might be using Laravel version 5.4.36 or something. 
So I think try by changing 'ACTION' to 'URL' as below.

```
{!!Form::open(['url' => ['PostsController@destroy', $post->id], 'method' => 'POST', 'class' => 'pull-right'])!!}
    {{Form::hidden('_method', 'DELETE')}}
    {{Form::submit('Delete', ['class' => 'btn btn-danger'])}}
{!!Form::close()!!}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `action` method is fine the way you wrote it. That error literally means that you don't have a controller named `PostsController@destroy`.

Just run:

```
php artisan route:list
```

If the controller exist, the `name` column would give you the prefix and method `Post.destroy` and in the same row the `action` column would give you the controller name `PostsController@destroy`. Obviously if those two conditions are not there; you get the error:

`Action App\Http\Controllers\PostsController@destroy not defined.`

Comment: this is a very relevant explanation. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use the `action` helper function like this `action('WelcomeController@log_in')` or you can just set the action to a route that provides you the controller.

Answer (score 0):

You've missed a step.

Think back to what the action attribute in an html form looks like:

```
action="{{ you put a url here, not a controller action }}"
```

Then consider your routes file, where you should add whatever route you decide to reference within `{{ }}` above, and map it to your controller action *in the routes file*.

I'd advise doing this without using Form::, then you will understand it better (and it's no more complicated).

Comment: Hi not sure what you mean about doing without Form::?

Comment: Form:: just generates html, i.e. <form>...</form>.  Write that yourself [instead](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp).

Answer (score 0):

juste you need to change method form inside your form to delete like this :

```
{!!Form::open(['action' => ['PostsController@destroy', $post->id], 'method' => 'DELETE', 'class' => 'pull-right'])!!}
    {{Form::hidden('_method', 'DELETE')}}
    {{Form::submit('Delete', ['class' => 'btn btn-danger'])}}
{!!Form::close()!!}
```

Comment: Thanks tried that but still same error message, thanks for the suggestion though.

Answer (score 0):

in Laravel 8 full description of the route is required as follows:

```
{!!Form::open(['action' => ['App\Http\Controllers\PostsController@destroy', $post->id], 
'method' => 'POST', 'class' => 'float-right'])!!}
```